# Adding swagger-UI with angular 10

Tags: reactjs, angular, swagger, single-page-application, swagger-ui

How to add **Swagger UI** in your angular application?

I have searched numerous times for this question and found only one solution is there and It was done using `swagger-ui-dist` package but in the latest release of the `https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui` tells that use `swagger-ui` instead of `swagger-ui-dist` for single-page applications.

There is a solution of adding this package to react and it is well explained.

**Swagger-UI with React - https://swagger.io/blog/api-documentation/building-documentation-portal-swagger-tutorial/**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I implemented this functionality in my angular application and thought that it can be helpful for other developers as well. I have searched it at multiple places and read multiple blogs.

Steps -

1. install swagger-ui

   `npm i swagger-ui`
2. Configure the angular.json file and swagger-ui CSS module to it.

```
  "styles": [ "./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css"]
```

3. Add the import statement of swagger-UI to your component.ts file.

   `import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui';`
4. Add the below code in your component's ngOnInit.

```
// example-swagger-exp.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
     SwaggerUI({
         domNode: document.getElementById('swagger-ui-item'),
         url: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json'
       });
 }
```

5. last part of this functionality,
   Add the below code to the HTML file of your component

   // swagger-exp.component.html

   ```
   <div id="swagger-ui-item"></div>
   ```

**Note** - One last important thing,

How can you add your swagger.json/swagger.yaml object in step 4?

**Simply replace the 'url' parameter with 'spec' and add your JSON object.**

```
      SwaggerUI({
          domNode: document.getElementById('api-data'),
          spec : your json object
        });
```

Comment: I would like to add that styles could be included into component styles (not project root) with simple @import "swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css"

this allows also to setup the documentation module as lazy loaded